# Как проверить turn сервер что корректно работает?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, nat, webrtc

установил coturn, настроил, запустил, вроде работает. Ключевое слово вроде, я хз работает или нет. Как узнать что turn сервер доступен из вне?

Comment: А чем от проброса портов отличается?

Comment: Эм.. Попытаться извне до него достучаться, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy ситуация такая. Из вне turn сервер вроде видно.

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко, тогда что ещё надо проверить?

Comment: @Qwertiy я сказал "вроде". Интересно было бы услышать варианты как это можно проверить, что бы я не говорил "вроде".

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой сервис - https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ - который позволяет проверить терн сервер. Единственное, что нужно знать - он проверяет с Вашего браузера. Поэтому, возможно нужно будет взять ноут и пойти в какое-нибудь кафе и там также проверить.

Comment: Можно через прокси проверить

Comment: а вот нет. Скорее всего не получиться.

Comment: почему не получится?

Comment: те я вбиваю там данные своего turn сервера, захожу на него с двух разных ip адресов, совершенно несвязанных друг с другом и если я их  обоих там наблюдаю то успех?

Comment: @Alex78191 потому что скорее всего прокси будет просто для http(s) трафика. А turn работает немного по другому.

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко вполне возможно.

Comment: @KoVadim браузеры тоже по HTTP работают.

Comment: А turn - нет:) Разберитесь, как оно там работает, что бы не возникало подобных вопросов.

Comment: @KoVadim прокси поддерживают метод CONNECT

Answer (score 1):

a) берем тупой html пример с webrtc, задаем в нем свой turn

b) запускаем с двух вкладок

c) смотрим кандидаты и логи coturn'а

d) в кандидатах должны быть строчки **relay** с IP'шником turn'а а в логах turn'а BIND сообщения

далее, по желанию - вырезаем из SDP host кандидаты и смотрим как работает relay